# Parsing audio format rates from USB Audio Interface fails, causing disconnect/rediscover loop

Tags: audio, alsa, usb-audio, alsamixer

When I connect my PreSonus USB AudioBox 96 to my Ubuntu 18.04LTS desktop via USB2.0 port, 
`dmesg` shows the following errors in a loop:

```
[ 8764.468004] usb 1-11: new high-speed USB device number 61 using xhci_hcd
[ 8764.516953] usb 1-11: New USB device found, idVendor=194f, idProduct=0303, bcdDevice= 1.12
[ 8764.516955] usb 1-11: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 8764.516957] usb 1-11: Product: AudioBox USB 96
[ 8764.516958] usb 1-11: Manufacturer: PreSonus
[ 8764.516959] usb 1-11: SerialNumber: 000000000000
[ 8769.723951] usb 1-11: 1:1: cannot set freq 96000 (v2/v3): err -110
[ 8774.843735] usb 1-11: parse_audio_format_rates_v2v3(): unable to retrieve number of sample rates (clock 5)
[ 8820.921855] usb 1-11: USB disconnect, device number 61
[ 8821.065655] debugfs: Directory '56' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 8821.193535] usb 1-11: new high-speed USB device number 62 using xhci_hcd
[ 8821.242166] usb 1-11: New USB device found, idVendor=194f, idProduct=0303, bcdDevice= 1.12
[ 8821.242168] usb 1-11: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 8821.242170] usb 1-11: Product: AudioBox USB 96
[ 8821.242171] usb 1-11: Manufacturer: PreSonus
[ 8821.242172] usb 1-11: SerialNumber: 000000000000
[ 8831.417276] usb 1-11: uac_clock_source_is_valid(): cannot get clock validity for id 5
[ 8836.537052] usb 1-11: parse_audio_format_rates_v2v3(): unable to retrieve number of sample rates (clock 5)
[ 8882.615203] usb 1-11: USB disconnect, device number 62
[ 8882.763151] debugfs: Directory '57' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 8882.890909] usb 1-11: new high-speed USB device number 63 using xhci_hcd
[ 8882.919108] usb 1-11: device descriptor read/8, error -71
[ 8883.055305] usb 1-11: device descriptor read/8, error -71
[ 8883.163566] debugfs: Directory '58' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 8883.498882] usb 1-11: new high-speed USB device number 64 using xhci_hcd
[ 8883.547227] usb 1-11: New USB device found, idVendor=194f, idProduct=0303, bcdDevice= 1.12
[ 8883.547229] usb 1-11: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 8883.547231] usb 1-11: Product: AudioBox USB 96
[ 8883.547232] usb 1-11: Manufacturer: PreSonus
[ 8883.547233] usb 1-11: SerialNumber: 000000000000
[ 8883.657682] usb 1-11: USB disconnect, device number 64
```

I suspect the failure is at [this](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/50cc09c18985eacbbd666acfd7be2391394733f5/sound/usb/format.c#L398) line of the linux kernel.

The interface is intermittently available as an input source in `alsamixer`. It will be available for a few seconds, then disappear, reappear, etc. The device works fine on my Windows machine.

Does anyone have any advice for how to debug/resolve this issue?

I've included the output of `lsusb -v` below.

```
Bus 001 Device 041: ID 194f:0303 PreSonus Audio Electronics, Inc. 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x194f PreSonus Audio Electronics, Inc.
  idProduct          0x0303 
  bcdDevice            1.12
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 3 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength          328
    bNumInterfaces          6
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Association:
      bLength                 8
      bDescriptorType        11
      bFirstInterface         0
      bInterfaceCount         3
      bFunctionClass          1 Audio
      bFunctionSubClass       0 
      bFunctionProtocol      32 
      iFunction               0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Control Device
      bInterfaceProtocol     32 
      iInterface             16 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (HEADER)
        bcdADC               2.00
        bCategory               8
        wTotalLength           75
        bmControl            0x01
          Latency control Control (read-only)
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 8
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype     10 (CLOCK_SOURCE)
        bClockID                5
        bmAttributes         0x03 Internal programmable Clock 
        bmControls           0x07
          Clock Frequency Control (read/write)
          Clock Validity Control (read-only)
        bAssocTerminal          0
        iClockSource            0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                17
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             1
        wTerminalType      0x0603 Line Connector
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bCSourceID              5
        bNrChannels             2
        bmChannelConfig   0x00000000
        bmControls    0x0000
        iChannelNames          32 
        iTerminal               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                12
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             2
        wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bSourceID               1
        bCSourceID              5
        bmControls         0x0000
        iTerminal               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                17
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             3
        wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bCSourceID              5
        bNrChannels             2
        bmChannelConfig   0x00000000
        bmControls    0x0000
        iChannelNames          48 
        iTerminal               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                12
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             4
        wTerminalType      0x0301 Speaker
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bSourceID               3
        bCSourceID              5
        bmControls         0x0000
        iTerminal               0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol     32 
      iInterface             17 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol     32 
      iInterface             17 
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                16
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (AS_GENERAL)
        bTerminalLink           2
        bmControls           0x00
        bFormatType             1
        bmFormats         0x00000001
          PCM
        bNrChannels             2
        bmChannelConfig   0x00000000
        iChannelNames          32 
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 6
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (FORMAT_TYPE)
        bFormatType             1 (FORMAT_TYPE_I)
        bSubslotSize            4
        bBitResolution         24
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0068  1x 104 bytes
        bInterval               1
        AudioControl Endpoint Descriptor:
          bLength                 8
          bDescriptorType        37
          bDescriptorSubtype      1 (EP_GENERAL)
          bmAttributes         0x00
          bmControls           0x00
          bLockDelayUnits         0 Undefined
          wLockDelay              0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol     32 
      iInterface             18 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol     32 
      iInterface             18 
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                16
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (AS_GENERAL)
        bTerminalLink           3
        bmControls           0x00
        bFormatType             1
        bmFormats         0x00000001
          PCM
        bNrChannels             2
        bmChannelConfig   0x00000000
        iChannelNames          48 
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 6
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (FORMAT_TYPE)
        bFormatType             1 (FORMAT_TYPE_I)
        bSubslotSize            4
        bBitResolution         24
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0068  1x 104 bytes
        bInterval               1
        AudioControl Endpoint Descriptor:
          bLength                 8
          bDescriptorType        37
          bDescriptorSubtype      1 (EP_GENERAL)
          bmAttributes         0x00
          bmControls           0x00
          bLockDelayUnits         0 Undefined
          wLockDelay              0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes           17
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Feedback
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
        bInterval               4
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        3
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Control Device
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface             16 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (HEADER)
        bcdADC               1.00
        wTotalLength            9
        bInCollection           1
        baInterfaceNr( 0)       4
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        4
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      3 MIDI Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      MIDIStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (HEADER)
        bcdADC               1.00
        wTotalLength           65
      MIDIStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 6
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (MIDI_IN_JACK)
        bJackType               1 Embedded
        bJackID                 1
        iJack                   0 
      MIDIStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 6
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (MIDI_IN_JACK)
        bJackType               2 External
        bJackID                 2
        iJack                   0 
      MIDIStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (MIDI_OUT_JACK)
        bJackType               1 Embedded
        bJackID                 3
        bNrInputPins            1
        baSourceID( 0)          2
        BaSourcePin( 0)         1
        iJack                   0 
      MIDIStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (MIDI_OUT_JACK)
        bJackType               2 External
        bJackID                 4
        bNrInputPins            1
        baSourceID( 0)          1
        BaSourcePin( 0)         1
        iJack                   0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bRefresh                0
        bSynchAddress           0
        MIDIStreaming Endpoint Descriptor:
          bLength                 5
          bDescriptorType        37
          bDescriptorSubtype      1 (GENERAL)
          bNumEmbMIDIJack         1
          baAssocJackID( 0)       1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bRefresh                0
        bSynchAddress           0
        MIDIStreaming Endpoint Descriptor:
          bLength                 5
          bDescriptorType        37
          bDescriptorSubtype      1 (GENERAL)
          bNumEmbMIDIJack         1
          baAssocJackID( 0)       3
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        5
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass       254 Application Specific Interface
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Device Firmware Update
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 
      iInterface             80 
      Device Firmware Upgrade Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                             9
        bDescriptorType                    33
        bmAttributes                       13
          Will Detach
          Manifestation Tolerant
          Upload Unsupported
          Download Supported
        wDetachTimeout                   2000 milliseconds
        wTransferSize                    1024 bytes
        bcdDFUVersion                   1.10
```

Comment: The interesting thing is that you get two **different** errors before the one you linked, first "cannot set freq 96000 (v2/v3)", and then "cannot get clock validity for id 5". It's possible the driver needs a quirk for your device. It's also possible a new kernel already has one, so upgrade to newest possible kernel and try again. If that doesn't help, I'd file a bug report with the developers of the sound usb modules, and see if they can develop a quirk code for your device.

Comment: The device repeatedly disconnects itself. I suspect that the firmware get confused by the Linux driver not behaving in exactly the same way as the Windows driver.

Answer (score 1):

I had an almost identical problem in Mint 20. It was solved by plugging it into  USB 3.0 instead of 2.0

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is a driver trouble and can not be solved without code intervention. For example the trouble with Line6 products in LKLM:

https://www.spinics.net/lists/kernel/msg3712667.html

https://www.spinics.net/lists/alsa-devel/msg93391.html